# %100 background image in container and how can do scale width to page

Tags: css

repeat-x background image in 500px container div and how can I scale background image to page width. I am sorry for my bad English. Have a look at the following image to understand my case.

[image]

```
.container {
width: 500px;
height: 60px;
background-color:#f2d88c;
}

.menubg {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background-image: url(bg.jpg)  center repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: What ould you like to achieve? To stretch bg .container (orange one) to 100%? 
I can think of these solutions:
1. setting body background to #f2d88c - depends on a layout, 
2. give .container 100% and put an extra div inside and this one would have width:500px...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3 elements and use this css

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #f2d88c;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menubg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(bg.jpg) center repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="menubg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: very happy to say why give me negative point , where in my codes is run ?

Comment: if you write me, I didn't give you negative point. when I try to give positive point I am getting "Upvote requires 15 reputation" error.

Comment: my friend , i dont say that to you , i know how do that and i say to him , I'm sorry for the misunderstanding occurred

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/PjGqv/9/

Your `div.menubg` is a child of `div.container` The child element cannot be wider then its 500px width parent.

You can use absolute positioning if the parent elements position it is relative to has a 100% width. I've included a jsfiddle

However by using `position: absolute;` you are taking the child out of the parents container. Depending on your situation, you would have to adjust its position values.

```
.menubg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;  
  background-image: url(bg.jpg)  center repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: if parent , container have position:relative , this dont work right

Comment: Thats why i said "You can use absolute positioning if the parent elements position it is relative to has a 100% width."

Comment: the code you use make the munebg position dont relate by container and set by body

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just added to menubg css: position:absolute; and left:0px; and this worked well.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```css
background-size: cover;
```

to the `.menubg`